# H2 DB in Spring Boot Hibernate does not generate Db Schema

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, h2

I want my Spring Application to autogenerate the DB schema and tables...
I've read some Q&A to this topic and I've set my DB URL to:

> H2DataSource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:tmp.db;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT
>   EXISTS GPSTRACKER");

and I've annotated my Entities like:

> @Entity 
>   @Table(name="tblGps", schema= "GPSTRACKER")

but the db schema is still not created.

Here is my log output.  Hibernate is trying to create the tables, but can't find the schema!

What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions?

**Log Output**

```
2015-04-20 22:29:38.211  INFO 7056 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2015-04-20 22:29:38.356  INFO 7056 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.8.Final}
2015-04-20 22:29:38.360  INFO 7056 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2015-04-20 22:29:38.362  INFO 7056 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2015-04-20 22:29:38.745  INFO 7056 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
2015-04-20 22:29:38.899  INFO 7056 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2015-04-20 22:29:39.202  INFO 7056 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.h.h.i.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory    : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2015-04-20 22:29:39.795  INFO 7056 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
2015-04-20 22:29:39.801 ERROR 7056 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: drop table GPSTRACKER.tbl_gps if exists
2015-04-20 22:29:39.801 ERROR 7056 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : Schema "GPSTRACKER" nicht gefunden
Schema "GPSTRACKER" not found; SQL statement:
drop table GPSTRACKER.tbl_gps if exists [90079-185]
```

**EntityManagerFactory**

```
@Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
        vendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform(MyAppSettings.getDbPlattform());

        HibernateJpaDialect jpd = new HibernateJpaDialect();
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        factory.setJpaDialect(jpd);
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setPackagesToScan(MyAppSettings.packagesToScan);
        factory.setDataSource(MyDataSource());

        return factory.getObject();
    }
```

**DataSource**

```
DriverManagerDataSource H2DataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
                H2DataSource.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
                H2DataSource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:tmp.db;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS GPSTRACKER");

                H2DataSource.setUsername("sa");
                H2DataSource.setPassword("");
```

@pvgoddijn i can't remember exactly, and i can't find the code right now. But I guess it was that I needed to return `LocalEntityManagerFactory` instead of `EntityManagerFactory`... or sth like that. good luck! maybe i can find the code the next days...

Comment: the url helped me, seems spring ignores the annotation on the entity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating your datasource, you need to set the hbm2ddl.auto property in order for the database to be created/updated on startup.

```
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
    H2DataSource.setConnectionProperties(properties);
```

You could also set the property in your hibernate.cfg.xml file

Other possible values are: validate | update | create | create-drop

Additional information about this and other properties can be found at: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional

Comment: thanks, but for the copy-pasters among us: properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");