# JPA: entity object is not appeared in the H2 console

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-data-jpa

In my spring app i have the below entity:

```
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Entity

public class Profile {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;

    String name;
    String address;
    String description;
    String img;

public Profile(String name, String address, String description, String img) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.description = description;
        this.img = img;
    }
```

}

and then the repository is:

```
@Repository
public interface ProfileRepository extends JpaRepository<Profile,Long> {

}
```

Here is my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

So, i expect when i go to the h2 console uri:

```
http://localhost:8080/h2-console/login.do?jsessionid=ae6ba7021a23e0ebb4a4844381546e72
```

It shows the table related to the object `Profile`.

The problem is: *there is no table called Profile.*

So, **why i don't have the profile table?**

The `application.properties` is empty

Here is how i connect to H2[image]

And when i run my application, it says:

```
[2m2017-06-29 10:07:21.106[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m51392[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36morg.hibernate.dialect.Dialect           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
[2m2017-06-29 10:07:21.557[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m51392[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36morg.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
[2m2017-06-29 10:07:21.557[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m51392[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36morg.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000230: Schema export complete
```

So, it seems that, **the application makes the schema of database**. Am i right?

Comment: Because you need to instruct SpringBoot to create the Schema. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29758136/h2-db-in-spring-boot-hibernate-does-not-generate-db-schema

Comment: Please share your application.properties

Comment: @Salman now you setup a db name in `application.properties`: *dbname*. So when you try to connect to db from H2 console (`http://localhost:8080/h2-console`) you have to use `jdbc:h2:mem:dbname` as 'JDBC URL'. Port 9092 you have to use from your IDE (or from over SQL tool) to connect to H2 DB server.

Answer (score 1):

you need to set h2 configuration in `application.properties`
write these lines

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb --> whatever url you find when open console
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if your main class that contains the annotation @SpringBootConfiguration is in the root of hierarchy of your package

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve so by writing the schema.sql file that creates tables and can load data by placing the file in your src/main/resources location. There are a lot of different ways you can do this. I like the schema.sql file because it has something that you can look at and manage.

Answer (score 0):

Then you open 'http://localhost:8080/h2-console' you need to specify 'JDBC URL'. By default (as I understand you use default setting because your application.properties is empty) this value is:

```
jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
```

---

IMHO H2 Console is not the best choice for the developer. You can work with H2 right from your IDE - see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43276769).

Comment: i have updated my question with ur hint, but still does not work

Comment: @Salman now you setup a db name in `application.properties`: *dbname*. So when you try to connect to db from H2 console (`http://localhost:8080/h2-console`) you have to use `jdbc:h2:mem:dbname` as 'JDBC URL'. Port 9092 you have to use from your IDE (or from over SQL tool) to connect to H2 DB server.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I **solved** it by moving the entity to the main app package.

Note: using @ComponentScan over the main app class didn't solve the issue nither a separate class with @Configuratin @ComponentScan ( basePackages =  {"thepackage"})